# TVector3D.AddVector3D does not work (for me)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

Using **Delphi XE4** (update1) and **FMX**, I want to **move camera** with this code (inside a wheel-mouse event) :

```pascal
AVector := Vector3D(0, 0, 3);
Camera.Position.Vector.AddVector3D(AVector);
```

The code compile, when do nothing. With de debugger, the `Camera.Position.Vector` value **does not change**.

When changing the lines with

```pascal
AVector := Vector3D(0, 0, 3);
Camera.Position.Vector := Camera.Position.Vector + AVector;
```

...it works !!! Strange enough as the `AddVector3D()` function do exactly this code !!!

```pascal
procedure TVector3D.AddVector3D(const AVector3D: TVector3D);
begin
  Self := Self + AVector3D;
end;
```

What's wrong with my code ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Camera.Position` is of type `TPosition3D`. And `TPosition3D.Vector` is a property of type `TVector3D` with a getter and a setter. Note that `TVector3D` is a record, which is a value type rather than a reference type. That detail is crucially important.

So, when you write `Camera.Position.Vector` you are referring to a copy of the vector. It is a copy because `TVector3D` is a value type.

So, the non-working code is equivalent to:

```
var
  TempVec: TVector3D;
....
TempVec := Camera.Position.Vector;
TempVec.AddVector3D(...);
```

Clearly the call to `AddVector3D` won't modify `Camera.Position` because the call to `AddVector3D` merely mutates the temporary local.

In your code, that temporary local variable is still present, but you have not given it a name. It's a hidden, implicit variable.

In order to modify the position, you must make an assignment to the `Vector` property, which is exactly what the working code does.

As a general rule, value types which support in-place mutation are generally indicative of poor design. So, in my view, the Embarcadero engineers should never have added the mutating instance methods like `AddVector3D`, `Normalize`, `Scale` and so on. Such methods lead to this confusion. Instead the functionality is better implemented with functions that return new values, just as the overloaded operators do.

Comment: @TridenT does this make sense?

Comment: I'm really surprised (and sad) to see that `Camera.Position.Vector` return a copy of the vector ... That's perfect David as always with your answers :) Thx for the details !

Comment: Returning a copy is just fine. It's conceptually no different from a property of type `Integer`, say, which also returns a copy because `Integer` is a value type. The difference is that `TVector3D` has instance methods that modify `Self`. The existence of those mutating instance methods is what leads to the confusion, in my view.